# Separate helper methods from test classes?

Tags: java, testing

When  testing, sometimes a helper method can be useful for repeated task e.g. in test setup.

*Concrete example*:
We have certain tests against our rest interface using Spring's `RestTemplate`. To make it easier, the requests are sent with the help of a helper method (let's call it method `A()` for now), which returns the objects from the response.

This helper method `A()` seems to pollute the test class, as it is a method which is actually not a test itself. Having multiple helper methods in a test class has a negative effect regarding the overview.

Is it acceptable to create a second class next to the test class, which is containing all helper method? What would be the difficulties if doing so? Or are there any other ways to keep a good overview of the test class?

- `MyTestClass` -> containing only methods which are a actuall test
- `MyTestClassUtil` -> containing all helper methods that are used by `MyTestClass`

Comment: wait.. explain the test again? don't you have a client to go with the api which you can run the tests against?

Comment: @Ewan It's an integration test in this case. The spring test suite will run the server implementation to test and the `RestTemplate` is simulating a client. Although I think this shouldn't really matter. The main issue is, that there is a helper method which is used by multiple tests.

Comment: Yes that is acceptable. It's hard to think of any difficulties, beyond your choice of name. `MyTestClassUtil` doesn't really tell me what that class is for. `MyTestClassCommonSetup` or some such would seem a better name.

Comment: I use to solve this with inheritance. Whether this good or bad, I only can say is that it works for me. Common methods and utilities of Integration-Tests are implemented in a superclass (abstract). Often I also use It for templating tests, initialize the tests framework, prepare settings, etc. It could be done with composition too, but I feel myself like implementing an API for tests over another API for test (Spring tests, JUnit, etc).

Comment: it sounds like your helpermethod IS the client? I would expect you to already have a MyApiClient class for each Api, you would then create integration tests of your Api using this client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to create a second class 
>   next to the test class, which is containing all helper method?

Not with **all** helper methods, but with helper methods that are used in more than one test class.

Design your tests the same way as you implement business classes!

Refactor code duplicates within a class into a local method. If the method is used in different test classes move it into a different test helper class that is used by different tests.

So my `OrderTests` class has a local method `assertEqual(String message, IOrder expected, IOrder actual)` and my helper `TestDataFactory` has a static method `createTestOrder()` that is used in `OrderTests`, `PriceCalculationTests`, `PaymentTests`, `DeliveryTests`.

A test may use one or more of the standard factory methods and modifies it as needed. Example:

```
DeliveryTests.executeOrderWithNoDeliveryAdressShouldThrow() {
    // a valid standard order with one article, user, deliveryadress, ...
    Order sut = TestDataFactory.createTestOrder(); 
    sut.setDeliveryAdress(null); // implements "WithNoDeliveryAdress"

    try {
        sut.execute(); // this should throw
        Assert.fail(); // this should never be reached because of exception.
    } catch(OrderNotCompleteException) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to Michael C. Feathers in [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://www.amazon.ca/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052) You can create what he called an Object Seam; A class implementing the interface you are testing, or inheriting from the class you are testing. in this case, you do not contaminate your original code with unit testing.